# What does "be set with something/someone" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It's from the 18th episode of the 10th season of *Friends*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/AyLeo-wyHJI). It's at around 3 minute and 44 seconds.

> Joey: I'm gonna miss these little guys. It was nice having birds
> around again.
>
> Chandler: Hey, you know what? Maybe we should keep them here with you.
>
> Joey: What?
>
> Chandler: Yeah, I mean we've got a lot going on right now. And, plus,
> here they'd have their own room.
>
> Joey: I could get a goose!
>
> Chandler: You know, I - I think **you're set with** the poultry.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, Chandler means that Joey already has enough birds and doesn't need more.